# Flutter - Is It OK to Put State in MyApp?

Tags: flutter, state-management

I was looking at Flutter's docs, and [this diagram](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) shows the cart model being put in MyApp. Now, in the flutter default project, MyApp is a StatelessWidget. Is that OK -- the idea being that you pass references to the model down via constructors -- or is it supposed to be an InheritedWidget? Or does it matter? Thanks for any insights ...

Comment: Hi does my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you can make MyApp a stateful widget. However sometimes that would not be efficient. For example, say you have a `int counter = 0;` in the state of MyApp. Then when you change counter, you call `setState(() {counter++;});` But then the **whole** MyApp will get rebuild! That takes some time if you app is complex.

Thus, I suggest some more automatic library, such as `MobX` (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx.dart). Personally I used it to write a simple project about 30k lines of flutter code and it works pretty well.

Comment: And RiverPod!  It wouldn't be me if I didn't mention riverpod. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Aha, sounds interesting!